# iOS - UITableview cells with shared surface

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

The default `UITableviewCell` frames order is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to create or change the cell's frame for having shared surface between them? (Swift)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cells are not designed to do that. You might be able to force that effect but it would likely have undesired consequences.